# QT connection with existing server with username and password

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I am working on adapter interface where i connect the simulator which i have constructed with an existing simulator running on a server.

I have been going through the QAbstractSocket and I have got some basic idea of it.

But the problem is the server that i am trying to access, has an authentication system, where i actually need to enter username and password credentials.

As long as i have gone through the class reference i have not got any solutions.

Can anyone please guide me of what QT class should i use or can tell me some ideas of how to access them?

Comment: Try to use QTcpServer class.

Comment: @user1929959 How does a TCP listen socket help with authentication???  In my opinion, we need to understand what this authentication system is exactly, e.g. SSH, etc...

Comment: pssst, what kind of authentication does this server use?